# Adding simple shortcut on the terminal, the right way

Tags: command-line, scripts, 22.04, paths

I am trying to add folder to PATH variable (for specific user only).

so to ~/.bashrc i have added

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/Tools/scripts/
```

within this folder i am having scripts and some shortcuts to other programs
(for example: firefox.sh)

When i open new terminal, path variable is correct but when i try to do "`sh firefox`" i get "No such file".

I want to be able to execute for this user any *.sh script from any folder from terminal
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: That is not how it works

Answer (score 1):

Scripts in your search path should have unique names(*different from other system commands including shell builtins*) i.e. avoid names such as `firefox, vlc, nano, echo, cd, test, sudo ... etc`.

Scripts in your search path are run by filename(*including extensions like e.g. `.sh` if used*) without specifying the shell interpreter(*these are executables that take their arguments as script files with full path or script command strings but not an executable/scriptfile in your path that you call by just its filename*) before it but rather include a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in it i.e. **not** like this:

```
sh scriptname
```

But rather like this:

```
scriptname
```

Scripts in your search path need to include a shebang(*The first line in the script that tells what interpreter should be used to run the script*) that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or this:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

or even this:

```
#!/bin/python3
```

and so on.

Scripts in your search path  need to be made executable first like so:

```
chmod +x /full/path/to/scriptname
```

That's how they work.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` and `sh` are different shells. I believe `~/.bashrc` would not be read by `sh`. Try putting your additional to the path in `~/.profile` which should get read by all shells.

Additionally, you wrote that you script is called `firefox.sh` so you would also need to reference it by `sh firefox.sh` - but this still might not work because the search path is only evaluate for executables, while in this case you try to load a script with `sh` and are not directly executing it.

Try

```
sh `which firefox.sh`
```

to first resolve the path. This would also fork if `firefox.sh` has the mode "x" (`chmod +x firefox.sh`)

Comment: An exported path with `export` will be available to `sh`(be it linked to `dash` or else*) and to any other installed shell if at least the containing file is sourced at least once per login.

Comment: Yes, true - if `sh` is called from a `bash` this would work.